# How do I get the last inserted 'id' from the forms table and add it to the 'form_id' in the attributes table?

Tags: cakephp, model

I have two tables,Forms and Attributes. I'm tring to retrieve the last inserted id from the Forms table and insert it to the form_id column of the Attributes table, along with the other field columns.

Earlier I retrieved the form Id from the Forms table and used it to update the value of the Form name column. It worked fine.The code for that is given below:

```
function saveFormName($data)
    {   
       $this->data['Form']['formname']=$data['Form']['formname'];
       $this->data['Form']['id']=$this->find('all', array(
                                    'fields' => array('Form.id'),
                                    'order' => 'Form.id DESC'
                                     ));
       $this->id=$this->data['Form']['id'][0];
       $this->saveField('name',$this->data['Form']['formname']);       
    }
```

But When  I tried to do it in a similar way for updating the attributes table,the row is not saved in the database,since the value of $this->data['Form']['id'][0] is an 'Array'.
Even in the saveFormName function, the value of $this->data['Form']['id'][0] is an 'Array',but the form name gets updated correctly. Someone explain me the concept.

```
function saveFieldEntries($data)
{   
        $this->data['Form']['id']=$this->find('all', array(
                                    'fields' => array('Form.id'),
                                    'order' => 'Form.id DESC'
                                     ));
          $this->data['Attribute']['form_id'] = $this->data['Form']['id'][0];

          $this->data['Attribute']['label']= 'Label';
          $this->data['Attribute']['size']='20';
          $this->data['Attribute']['type']=$data['Attribute']['type'];
          $this->data['Attribute']['sequence_no'] = $data['Attribute']['sequence_no'];
          $this->Attribute->save($this->data);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, here is the corresponding code in the controller.

```
 function insertFormName()
    {    
    $this->data['Form']['formname']=$this->params['form']['formname'];
    $this->Form->saveFormName($this->data);
    }


    function insertFieldEntry()
    {
    $this->data['Attribute']['type']=$this->params['form']['type'];
    $this->data['Attribute']['sequence_no'] = $this->params['form']['sequence_no'];
    $this->Form->saveFieldEntries($this->data);
    }
```

The parameters form name,type and sequence no are passed to the controller from the corresponding view file.

Comment: Please explain in further detail the process behind these two functions.  How does the data arrive at each?  Is there a form somewhere that gets posted and these functions are subsequently called by the relevant controller action?  I think you're making this more difficult that it needs to be, but I can't really give a solution until I see more of the code (both models and controllers would be ideal, if you can swing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->data['Form']['id'][0] holds an array because find('all') returns an array.

So if you need first ID from this array, you need to pick it properly in function saveFieldEntries:

```
...
$this->data['Attribute']['form_id'] = $this->data['Form']['id'][0]['Form']['id'];
...
```